# Track Last of For Loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am learning PHP. I am using for loop like below in one of my php function.

```
$numbers = $data["data"];
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($numbers);$i++) {
    $w->send($numbers[$i]);
    }
```

I want check that if its last number, I need sleep some second and want call one other function. I do not know how can I do it. can anyone please suggest me what should I do for it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$numbers = $data["data"];
    for ($i = 0,$c=count($numbers);$i < $c;$i++) {
        $w->send($numbers[$i]);
        if($i==$c-1){
            sleep(60);
            //call your function here;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do, what you want to do, after the loop:

```
$numbers = $data["data"];

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
  $w->send($number);
}

$w->send($otherNumber);
sleep($forSomeSeconds);
```

I also changed the `for` loop to a `foreach` loop after the comment made by Elementary.

Comment: @Elementary I agree. I will change that.